# Audio memory game

Tags: javascript, audio, getelementbyid

I am trying to code a memory game where instead of matching words or images, I match sound.

I am doing this with javascript (based on this code: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KQXWZx) and I already got the game to play a sound when I click on an element the way I want it to, but now they all play the same sound which defeats the purpose of the game.....

The code is quite hard to explain here but long story short: I cant figure out why this:

```
document.getElementById("audio-tay").src = "sounds/"+ picked +".m4a";    
   tay.play();
```

is not working, while this:

```
document.getElementById("audio-tay").src = "sounds/bomt.m4a";    
   tay.play();
```

does work (in this case I change the sound but I still have the same problem of all elements being the same sound).

Here is my entire code:

https://codepen.io/8ergloind/pen/bLJzBe

not working because it is missing all img's and audio's, 
but if somebody can help despite that I would be eternally grateful!

Comment: console.log() will be your lifeblood throughout your dev career. Make sure to use it. On doing a console.log(picked) you'll find that this.value is returning none. I wuold love testing a working example

Comment: Thanks, will look into it! but I can't provide a working example now, there are so many files with specific names connected to it..